# Is executeUpdate method in Java thread-safe

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have multiple threads trying to update a MySQL database? is executeUpdate method thread-safe to use?

Comment: Some more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272453/jdbc-fundamental-concepts-pooling-and-threading

Comment: if you have multiple threads, you should use multiple connections. simple as that.

Comment: In addition to worrying about thread safety, you may also need to consider concurrent database access (transactions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not thread-safe to use.

In fact, if some other thread uses a statement, and then another thread calls executeUpdate(), then the other thread's `ResultSet`s, if any, will be closed. [JavaDoc for java.sql.Statement (of which PreparedStatement is a subtype)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)  "All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists."

Furthermore, it's unlikely that a given implementation of `executeUpdate()` would be written to be mulit-thread safe.

You should either syncrhonize all use of the statement and resulting result sets, or make multiple connections so that each thread uses its own JDBC `Connection` to the database..  I would recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your update methods using a synchronized keyword and think about your concurrency threads deadlocks there