# Is executeUpdate method in Java a thread-safe one?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

In my application,there are **multiple threads trying to insert** to a **MySQL** database.Is **executeUpdate** method **thread-safe to use**?How can I make this work?

Comment: See this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828202/is-executeupdate-method-in-java-thread-safe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `executeUpdate` method in itself may be thread safe, prepared statements are not designed to be used concurrently. This is because each instance stores your parameters until `executeUpdate` instructs it to send the parameters to MySQL. Moreover, since transactions are managed through `Connection` objects, sharing connections concurrently without synchronization may give you undesired behavior on commits/rollbacks.

In order to make inserts from multiple threads work concurrently, each thread needs to use its own `Connection`, and make its own `PreparedStatement`. Using multiple prepared statements concurrently on the same database is thread safe, because the concurrency is managed on the RDBMS side.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the Javadoc that says either a `Connection,` a `PreparedStatement,` or a `ResultSet` is threadsafe, and therefore none of their methods are either.

Answer (score 0):

`executeUpdate()` is not thread-safe to use for multiple threads.

you can make multiple connections so that each thread uses its own JDBC Connection to the database.